# Is it possible to show totals (summary) row under the header row in jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I would like to put the totals (summary) row under the header row in jqGrid? Is this possible?

Detailed explanation:

Go to: http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html
In the left nav menu go to : Grouping -> Remote Data (sorted with grandtotals)

See the last 'Totals' line at the bottom of the grid. I would like to put that line under the header row at the top.
(I don't need grouping)

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correct you want to change position of the footer row (which created if you use `footerrow:true`) on the top of the grid body direct under the grid columns. To do this you can do following

```
$("div.ui-jqgrid-sdiv").after($("div.ui-jqgrid-bdiv"));
```

or

```
var grid = $("#list"); // your grid
var gview = grid.closest("ui-jqgrid-view"); // get div#gview_list
$("div.ui-jqgrid-sdiv",gview[0]).after($("div.ui-jqgrid-bdiv",gview[0]));
```

if you want to do the movement of the footer only on one specifig grid on the page.