# Disable sort on specific row in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid with the first row's label as "Total". It will have totals of each column in those particular cells. I want this row to be disabled from sorting. Is there any option in jqgrid to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you fill the grid in a wrong way. jqGrid allows to create *special summary (footer) row* by using `footerrow: true`. One can place the data in the row by usage of `footerData` method for example. If you follow the way then you will have no described problems: jqGrid will sort *the data* of the grid only, but the data from the summary div will stay unchanged. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5402655/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5633492/315935) shows how one can move the "footer" on top of the grid.